# How to edit column value before binding in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have the following grid like below

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvVegetationZone" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Style="width: 100%"
        ShowHeader="False" AllowSorting="false" OnRowEditing="gvVegetationZone_RowEdit"
        DataKeyNames="VegetationZoneID" OnRowDataBound="gvVegetationZone_RowDataBound"
        SkinID="gvGreyHead">
        <Columns>
                 <asp:Label ID="lblRedFlagData" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "RedFlag")) ? "Yes" : "No"%>' />
```

on my code behind i am trying to set the value based on condition to particular column but not sure how to do, hope someone will guide me here.

```
 Assessment.tblVegetationZoneRow[] VegetationZoneData
                = (Assessment.tblVegetationZoneRow[])objAssessment.tblVegetationZone.Select("SaveType <> " + Convert.ToString((int)EnumCollection.SaveType.RemoveOnly));

            if((sitecurrentscore <=34) && (VegetationZoneData[0].EECID >0 || VegetationZoneData[0].PercentageCleared >70))
            {
                gvVegetationZone.Columns[5].value = false;

            }

            gvVegetationZone.Columns[5].Visible = true;
            this.gvVegetationZone.DataSource = VegetationZoneData;
            this.gvVegetationZone.DataBind();
```

I have no clue so far how to set the value before binding, i was trying like this but no luck

by the way lblRedFlagData is my column[5] in my gridview
 gvVegetationZone.Columns[5].value = false;

Answer (score 0):

USE rowdatabound

```
      void gvVegetationZone_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)

     {
        if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)  

        {

             string cellVALUE = e.Row.Cells[1].Text;

             switch(cellVALUE )
             {
              case :
               e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "column value";

             }

    }



   }
```